# Flash CS 5.5 Unexpected File Format

Tags: flash, actionscript

I have been working on a flash movie all day.I shutdown my computer and rebooted it.Now when I go to open my .fla it says "unexpected file format".

I stupidly wrote all actionscript on the timeline.

What could be the problem?

Is there anyway to salvage this file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.fla` is a proprietary, binary file. So if Flash is not able to open it, then I guess it is damaged and can’t be opened.

Comment: I've had this happen before when a Flash file crashed. I'm yet to find a way of resurrecting it. I know it's in retrospect, but I always keep a duplicate of my .fla files for this very reason.

Comment: Yeah I forgot to mention I forced closed Flash when I rebooted.Man this is a hard lesson learned!

Comment: Luckily my Decompiler saved the day.

Comment: Thanks.I was a little frustrated!